# How to make an arrow appear on hover on a ListView,which is set with an horizontal scroll, and when clicked it scrolls throught the ListView

Tags: flutter

I want something like this on amazon where the arrows appear when you hover at the edge of the list. I have searched but found nothing, maybe someone could help me with this please.

[image: Amazon]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import
> 'package:frontend_fst/utilities/constants.dart'; import
> 'package:frontend_fst/components/cards.dart';
> 
> class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {   static const String id =
> 'main_screen_web';
> 
>   @override   _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState(); }
> 
> class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {   late FSTCards
> cards = const FSTCards();
> 
>   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>         appBar: PreferredSize(
>           preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(70),
>           child: AppBar(
>               centerTitle: true,
>               title: Image.asset(companyLogo, height: 80, width: 85)),
>         ),
>         body: SingleChildScrollView(
>           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
>           child: Center(
>             child: Column(
>               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
>               children: [
>                 SizedBox(
>                     height: 210,
>                     child: ListView.separated(
>                         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
>                         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
>                         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
>                           return cards;
>                         },
>                         separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
>                           return const SizedBox(width: 100);
>                         },
>                         itemCount: 20)), 
>               ],
>              ),
>             ),
>            ),
>           );
>          } 
>         }
```

Comment: Perhaps Amazon is the wrong example, AFAIK they are not written in Flutter and also do not publish their source code. Have you tried to find a Flutter application that has what you're looking for and has the source code so that you can take a peek? I'd personally would also look for three examples so that similarities and differences across multiple implementations can be discovered easily.

Comment: this may help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142634/place-an-arrow-at-the-end-of-the-horizontal-listview-flutter

Comment: you should try using `stack` widget to place the Arrows over the `listview` items. (I have not tried it, but it should work)

Comment: You should checkout MouseRegion widget
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html